# i want to match exactly contact-us page but not working

Tags: php, preg-match

i want to match `contact-us` page exactly present in the `url`

the combination could be..

```
contact.*        i,e(extension could be .html or .php or .aspx)
contact-us.*     i,e(extension could be .html or .php or .aspx)
contact.*        i,e(extension could be .html or .php or .aspx)
contactUs.*      i,e(extension could be .html or .php or .aspx)
```

without extension

```
contact        i,e(no extension)
contact-us    i,e(no extension)
contact       i,e(no extension)
contactUs     i,e(no extension)
```

right now i'm using this code which matches everything

```
$page = "http://www.example.com/contact-usmsdnds";
if(preg_match('/contact|contact-us|contact-us(.php|html)|contact(.php|html)/siU',$page)){
    echo "Matched";
 }else{
   echo "No Match";
}
```

**here is a demo** : http://phpio.net/s/1i2p

i'm ready to accept solution with totally different code

please help me thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try `'~/contact(?:-us|Us)?\.(?:aspx|php|html)/?$~i'`. The last `/?` matches an optional `/` at the end (not sure it should be there).

Comment: Use `if (strpos($url,'contact-us') !== false)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, your answer works perfectly thanks alot

Comment: Wait, but it seems you need to match URLs like `http://www.example.com/contact-us/`? Then try [`'~/contact(?:-us|Us)?(?:\.(?:aspx|php|html))?/?$~'`](https://regex101.com/r/djIZGD/1). Does that work better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
'~/contact(?-i:-us|Us)?(?:\.(?:aspx|php|html))?/?$~i'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/djIZGD/2)

It matches:

- `/contact` - a substring `/contact`
- `(?:-us|Us)?` - an optional substring `-us` or `Us`
- `(?:\.(?:aspx|php|html))?` - an optional sequence of a `.` + any of the alternatives substrings ()
- `/?` - an optional `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Note that `(?-i:...)` is a modifier group where the alternatives are matched in a case insensitive way (the general `/i` modifier at the end does not affect this group).

Comment: I tried to reflect the "match exactly" requirement with alternations inside a modifier group. If it is not really necessary, you may replace `(?-i:` with `(?:`. Besides, you may further tune this by playing around with the `?` modifiers or adding/removing alternatives in groups.